# Max-width property is not working with form and bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

login.html file:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container login-page-form">
    <form id="login-form" action="/auth/login" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Email">Email Address</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" name="email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control"  name="password">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

main.css file:

```
#login-form {
    margin-top: 25px
}

.login-page-form {
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

I have attached code for the both html and CSS file.
I am using bootstrap to design my html page and wants to add some of my own CSS property to form as max-width.

Answer (score 1):

Target the elements and use !important to override the Bootstrap CSS.

```
#login-form {
    margin-top: 25px !important;
}

.login-page-form {
    max-width: 200px !important;
}
```

Comment: Do try to avoid `!important` where you can - it gets annoying after a while (I learnt this the hard way :))

Comment: Thanks, I tried using !important and it still doing same thing. If i remove the container class and use only login-page-form as class it still does not apply CSS properties.